# Firebase Dynamic Links IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have setup firebase for receiving **universal links** and **custom url schemes**. I have 2 issues here,

- Clicking links on the app like whatsapp opens the browser but not the
  app, however, if I get the link to the notes app and open it, it
  shows an option of "open in app" after doing this, everytime I open
  it in whatsApp it seems to work fine.
- When I try to open links via chrome from the email app, it redirects
  to the app via custom url scheme, however the problem is that, the
  next time I open the app, it tends to repeat the action. Although I
  have already handled the custom url scheme previously, I dont know
  why its trying to do it again, kinda freaks me away.

Comment: When you open the link from the Notes app, are you just clicking it or are you long-pressing and selecting "Open in [app]" from the drop-down menu?

Comment: @AlexBauer For the first time I did long press but from the next time it seemed to work from just clicking it

Comment: That is expected. Disabling and enabling (which is what you are doing with the long-press) Universal Links is a one-time thing that stays in effect until you make another choice.

Comment: @AlexBauer But on the apps like whatsapp or so , there isnt an option which says "open in app". I had to get it into notes and then long press to do it